# twitter streaming <typeError> <RESPONSE [200]

Tags: twitter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, tweepy

error in streaming
[image: Twitter Streaming <typeError> <RESPONSE [200]>]

```
def get_tweets():
    url = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json'
    query_data = [('language', 'en'), ('locations', '-130,-20,100,50'),('track','#')]
    query_url = url + '?' + '&'.join([str(t[0]) + '=' + str(t[1]) for t in query_data])
    response = requests.get(query_url, auth=my_auth, stream=True)
    print(query_url, response)
    return response
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to fix the error in streaming?